# If and then error codes

Tags: vba, excel

Another noobie question.  Im trying to hide all columns in row 5 on a particular sheet if the cell is not empty and that cell is equal to 0.  I got it working at one point not using z as integer but i couldnt fit the not empty condition (columns with an empty 5th row cell were being hidden because the default value was zero).  Would appreciate any help.  Separate question, is there a quick and dirty way to reset your workbook back to a certain "saved state"? Thank you.

```
Dim wsOut As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim z As Integer

Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
Set rng = wsOut.Range("B:AA")

For z = 1 To 26
    If (Not IsEmpty(wsIn.Cells(5, z))) And wsIn.Cells(5, z).Value = 0 Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next z
```

End Sub

Comment: Yeah. [Start using source control](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/vba-and-git/). Unfortunately, the `DevTools` module in that repo is a bit busted right now, and I've not had time to fix it because I'm working on [Integrating the VBA Editor with Git](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/milestones/Source%20Control%20Integration). You can watch the Rubberduck repo to get updates on that.

Answer (score 3):

ok nvm i made it simpler and this worked...

```
Sub HideColumn()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B5:AA5")
      If cell = 0 And Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
           cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
       End If
   Next cell
End Sub
```